# Swift 2: play sound for different images in array

Tags: arrays, swift, audio, avfoundation, playback

I got an array of images

```
var cardImages = ["bellota", "manzana", "botas"]
```

I created myAudioPlayer to play sounds

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("correct", ofType: "wav")

    if let filePath = filePath
    {

        let filePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        do {

            try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL)


        } catch {

            print("error")

        }

    }
```

Next button that changes the image

```
  @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if imageIndex < 0 {

        imageIndex = maxImages
    }


    cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardImages[imageIndex])

    imageIndex++

    if imageIndex > maxImages {

        imageIndex = 0
    }

    cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardImages[imageIndex])
}
```

playSound Button:
What I'm trying to do in this method is play a sound when the image changes. Have a different sound for every image in the array. How can I do this? For example "apple" will play sound1, "orange" will play sound 2 when the next image is pressed

```
 @IBAction func playButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {


    myAudioPlayer.play()


}
```

Comment: is it in the same controller where you keep your array of sounds?

Comment: Yes. It's in the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate your audio loading into function:

```
func setTrack(audioName: String){


    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioName, ofType: "wav")

    if let filePath = filePath
    {

        let filePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        do {

            try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL)


        } catch {

            print("error")

        }

    }
}
```

Then, in nextButtonPressed:

```
@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if imageIndex < 0 {

        imageIndex = maxImages
    }


    cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardImages[imageIndex])

    imageIndex++

    if imageIndex > maxImages {

        imageIndex = 0
    }

    cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardImages[imageIndex])
    self.setTrack(audioList[imageIndex]) // or any other index you need/you have
}
```

Comment: `self.setTrack(audioList[imageIndex])`  for this I get error message: "Use of unresolved indentifier 'audioList'

Comment: audioList is the array of your songs